# How can i pluck the emements from the array based on a value in an array?

Tags: reactjs

How can i pluck the emements from the array based on a value in an array? I have an array of values

```
var userId = ["6","7"];
array = [{id: 5, first_name: "abc"}
         {id: 6, first_name: "def"}
         {id: 7, first_name: "ghi"}
         {id: 8, first_name: "jkl"} ]
```

In ReactJs is there any option to get a result array based on the userId? I need the result as

```
resultArray = [{id: 6, first_name: "def"}
               {id: 7, first_name: "ghi"}]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can use two for loop to get the following data in javascript, correct ?

Comment: Can u paste the whole code here, then I can add the js logic to that code for u, I am not aware of any reactjs in built method that would directly do what u need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
 within [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like so:

```js
// User Ids.
const userIds = [
  '6', 
  '7'
]

// Input: Users.
const array = [
  {
    id: 5,
    first_name: "abc"
  }, {
    id: 6,
    first_name: "def"
  }, {
    id: 7,
    first_name: "ghi"
  }, {
    id: 8,
    first_name: "jkl"
  }
]

// Output: Matches.
const output = array.filter((user) => userIds.includes(`${user.id}`))

// Log.
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Pretty coooool!